# Create web site using Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, web-services

Today when i was reading article about [**APPCode**](http://www.stewarthector.com/blog/jetbrains-appcode-review-an-improvement-over-xcode/) IDe they had written they support CSS, Javascript & html . After this I surfed few website where i found some info about [Cappuccino](http://www.cappuccino-project.org/#features) which is exactly like xocde IDe.

How far the objective-c supports in creating web site application, does the objective-c ends with iOS & OSx are they any frameworks which we used in creating UI for web site  .

Answer (score 1):

**XCode IDE** supports development on C, C++, Objective-C, Objective-C++, Java, AppleScript, Python and Ruby mainly. Although you can write some HTML files it is not the best choice as IDE for web development. There are plenty many outside like [TextMate](http://macromates.com/), [Coda](http://panic.com/coda/), or the two you mentioned APPCode and Cappuccino. 
**Objective-C**, programming language, mainly purpose is to develop software for iOS and OSX, but there some frameworks that lets you use it for web development like [GNUstepWeb](http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/GNUstepWeb) or [fronthkit](https://code.google.com/p/frothkit/). However it hasn't been updated since 2010, probably because of more mature frameworks like [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) and [Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Xcode is a great IDE if you are doing iOS / Mac OS X development.
Cappuccino, as a framework (not an IDE), uses objective-j and patterns found in Apple's Cocoa framework.

For Cappuccino development, I design my user interfaces in Xcode and write in Sublime Text 2.

Apple's framework (and Cappuccino) is complex, but worth it.   As a hobbyist developer, it took a while to learn.

If you are looking to make desktop quality apps for the web, I'd +1 Cappuccino.